# Cannot bind Margin property?

Tags: wpf, layout, binding, converters, margin

I am trying to have a sort of animated film strip where only one of its fields is visible at the given moment. Like a film strip in a camera - only one film field is currently placed under the lens and prepared to be enlighted. I try to achieve it as a grid withing an another grid. "Film strip" is called pageContainer in the code below. In the code behind I do an animation which is changing the Margin property of pageContainer grid. Works perfectly, pageContainer is nicely sliding to the left or to the right as I wish. For example: To show the page no. 2 the margin is set to (-270,0,0,0) instead of (0,0,0,0). That moves pageContainer to the left and only the second field is visible instead of the first one.

However as soon as I start resizing the whole UI, this mechanism stops to work and user can see a border between the two pages (fields) instead of only the current one. If I put breakpoint to my pageWidthConverter it is always hit when resizing the whole UI. If I put another breakpoint to pageMarginConverter it is never hit during the resizing. Why? I would like to make the Margin property dependent on BackgroundRectangle ActualWidth similarly as I made it with the Width property. But that does not work. Why is Width dynamically set while resizing the window, but Margin is not???

PS: Instead of using Margin one could use TranslateTransform. I tried but no success either.

If anybody can help it would be so highly appreciated.

Cheers
Hans

```
        ... <Grid Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,-4,0,0" ClipToBounds="True">
                <Grid x:Name="pageContainer"
                      Width="{Binding Converter={StaticResource pageWidthConvertor}, ElementName=BackgroundRectangle, Path=ActualWidth}"
                      Margin="{Binding Converter={StaticResource pageMarginConvertor}, ElementName=BackgroundRectangle, Path=ActualWidth}" >

                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=BackgroundRectangle, Path=ActualWidth}"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=BackgroundRectangle, Path=ActualWidth}"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=BackgroundRectangle, Path=ActualWidth}"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=BackgroundRectangle, Path=ActualWidth}"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions> ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need your margin to be dependant on two things (1) The offset you desire and (2) some proportion of your ActualWidth, in order for your UI to scale nicely. Have you tried using a MultiBinding? Take a look at the following article:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WpfWinFormsBulletGraphs.aspx#layout

This uses a multi-binding to scale some value based on the size of the control. Here is the multi-binding:

```
class ScalingMultiConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, 
            object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (!ValuesPopulated(values))
            return 0.0;

        double containerWidth = (double)values[2];
        double valueToScale = (double)values[1];
        double maximum = (double)values[0] ;

        return valueToScale * containerWidth / maximum;
    }

    private bool ValuesPopulated(object[] values)
    {
        foreach (object value in values)
        {
            if (value==null || value.Equals(DependencyProperty.UnsetValue))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, 
                object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And an example of its usage:

```
<Rectangle.Width>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ScalingMultiConverter}">
        <Binding Path="(c:BulletGraphWithLegend.GraphRange)"/>
        <Binding Path="(c:BulletGraphWithLegend.FeaturedMeasure)"/>
        <Binding Path="ActualWidth"/>
    </MultiBinding>
</Rectangle.Width>
```

You should be able to create a multi-binding that takes your desired offset and the ActualWidth and converts it into a Margin.

On another note, why not wrap your Grid in a Canvas and position it via the Canvas.Left property? This way you will not have to construct a Thickness in your converter.

Comment: Hi Colin, works like a charm ;) Many thanks!!! You are right, Canvas.Left is a better approach. I switched to it, I created a new custom property called CurrentFieldNumber and I used MultiBinding. To explain more about my original problem: My animation overwrote the binding! [explained here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/598139/oneway-binding-stops-working-after-the-target-manually-updated)  So now I let the animation run over my new CurrentFieldNumber and all is good :)  Thanks once again for your neat example! Hans