# Newbie question: how to bind to a part of the Margin property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'm taking my first steps in WPF binding, and I would like to bind two visual components: a `DataGrid` and a `Label`, the latter to be put above the other (not in front of it, I mean).

This is what I currently have:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dg_SomeTable" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="auto"
       Margin="10,26,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="74"/>
<Label Content="SomeTable" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,0"
       VerticalAlignment="Top" 
       Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=dg_SomeTable}"/>
```

As you can see, the `Label`'s width is bounded to the width of the `DataGrid`.
This is already useful, but I'd like to go a step further, and not only bind the width, but also the X-coordinate.

I believe that that X-coordinate is the first entry of the `Margin` property, but I can't simply bind to that whole property, because this would place my `Label` in front of my `DataGrid`.

I have already done some very naïve steps:

- I tried working with `Margin.x` or `Margin.X` or ..., but that seems not to work.
- I tried replacing `Margin` with `Left` but that seems not to exist and I'm out of inspiration.

Does anybody know the good way to bind the X-coordinate of one visual component to the X-coordinate of another visual component, when the definition of the X-coordinates are embedded in the `Margin` property?

Oh, I checked [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892444/cannot-bind-margin-property) but this involves actual programming, and I'm wondering if there's a simple XAML solution for this seemingly basic question.

**Edit after comment, asking for more information:**

Generally my XAML looks as follows:

```
<TabControl ...
    <TabItem ...
        <Grid ...
            <DataGrid x:Name="dg_SomeTable" ... Margin=... />
            <Label Content="SomeTable" ... />
```

As proposed, this should be replaced by something like:

```
<TabControl ...
  <TabItem ...
    <Canvas ...
      <DataGrid x:Name="dg_SomeTable" Width="222" Canvas.Left="10" ...
      <Label Content="SomeTable"
             Canvas.Left="{Binding Path=Left, 
                           RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                                           AncestorType={x:Type Canvas}}}"
             Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth,
                     ElementName=dg_Locations}"/>
```

I can already hear your reaction "*Now you are referring to the left of the `Canvas` where it's located in, while you should refer to the `Canvas.Left` of the `DataGrid`*".
Well, I tried these:

```
Canvas.Left="{Binding Path=Canvas.Left, ElementName=dg_SomeTable}"
Canvas.Left="{Binding Path=Left, ElementName=dg_SomeTable}"
```

None of them worked.

How can I refer to the `Canvas.Left` of the `DataGrid`?

Comment: The only way i can think to do it is to bind to the Margin property, then use a binding converter to extract the part of the margin you want (Margin.Left), then pass back a new Margin object with your desired values

Comment: Could you show us what your layout should look like, and why you need to do this complex binding? There might be ways around all that. Very rarely does WPF require manually positioning things. That being said: using Margin to position controls is generally not what you want. There are other ways, the easiest being placing the controls inside a canvas: then you can set Left, Right, Top and Bottom to position the control.

Comment: @Shrimperator: I edited my question according to your comment, can you have another look?

Comment: I still don't get the problem. If you just want the label above the DataGrid, why can't you just put them in a StackPanel. If you want them to share a margin, just put the margin in that StackPanel (or whatever container you go with)

Comment: I don't understand anymore: I want to put some `DataGrid` visual components, one next to the other. As a `Grid` gives the possibility to define column width definitions, I decided to use `Grid`s. Then I wanted to add a `Label` above each of my `DataGrid` components, but as the binding didn't work, I replaced my `Grid` with a `Canvas`. Now this also seems not to work, so I tried using a `StackPanel`, but this messes up my whole GUI. What can I do?

Comment: If you shoot me a picture of what the layout should look like, I'll post you a solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I refer to the Canvas.Left of the DataGrid?

Like this (note the parentheses around the attached property name):

```
Canvas.Left="{Binding Path=(Canvas.Left), ElementName=dg_SomeTable}"
```

Comment: You can do that using an IValueConverter, which would be a similar method to the link you shared that showed actual programming.

Answer (score 1):

Use converter

Step1. Make Converter

```
    public class MarginConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (!(value is Thickness)) return new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);

            Thickness gridMargin = (Thickness)value;

            return new Thickness(gridMargin.Left, 0,0,0);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return parameter;
        }
    }
```

Step2. Add to resource

```
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:MarginConverter x:Key="MarginConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
```

Step3. Bind Margin with converter

```
<Label Content="SomeTable" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
   VerticalAlignment="Top" 
   Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=dg_SomeTable}"
   Margin="{Binding Margin, ElementName=dg_SomeTable, Converter= {StaticResource MarginConverter}}"/>
```

This converter get dg_SomeTable's Margin and return
new Margin ( dg_table's Margin.Left, 0 , 0, 0 )